# Firebase Offline Support: upload posts while user is offline and sync when user comes online in iOS Swift app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using firebase in an iOS-Swift project in which I have to enable offline support for uploading posts, in the post there is a picture and caption just like Instagram, so what I want is when user is offline and he/she wants to upload a post, his/her picture get saved in cache and when user comes online that photo get uploaded and give back a download url that we can use for saving posts-details it in database.

sample code is:

```
                let photoIDString = UUID().uuidString
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "storage ref URL").child("posts").child(photoIDString)

                storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                guard let metadata = metadata else {
                    return
                }
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { ( url, error ) in
                    guard let downloadURL = url else {
                        return
                    }
                    let photoUrl = downloadURL.absoluteString
                    self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl)
                    })
                }
                )
```

I want to know what changes should I make in my code to provide the offline capability. Any code snippet will help more.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share the code you have written so far so we can help you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is better view as re-send to server when there is an error.
For your offline case, you can check if the **error** return is a network error, or manually check network connection availability.

You can create a re-send array of object 
e.g

```
var resendList : [YourObjectType]

// when failed to send to server
resendList.append(yourFailedObject)
```

And then, 2 solutions:

1. Check the network connectivity manually and reupload in when the app become active in `func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)` in appDelegate. For checking connectivity you can try the method here: [Check for internet connection with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift) But this has a problem that, the user has to go out the app and back again **with network connected**
2. Keep track(listen to notification) on the connectivity change, using a suggestion method by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27310748/4919289 and reupload it to server

and loop through all objects in resendList and re-upload again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an iOS developer, but I can share logical flow and some references.

When user clicks on upload: Check if network is available?

- if yes: upload the post.
- if no:

  - save the post to app storage or offline database
  - set broadcast receiver to receive broadcast when device comes online. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647477/how-application-will-get-to-know-availability-of-internet-connection-in-iphone) may be helpful.
  - upload post when device comes online.

If you are looking for solution that is offered by Firebase, you may find more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase offers you plenty of ways to do this in their documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities

When uploading to the firebase server, it will queue itself and wait until it has a internet connection again to upload. If this happens to timeout or you want to do it your own way just attempt to upload with a completionHandler on the `setValue` or `updateChild` functions - if not successfully and the error message is because of internet, add it to a local cache to the phone with the data and the path to the firebase server.

onLoad, attempt the same upload again until it succeeds, once it succeeds - clear the local cache.